# C# custom control property: unable to set DefaultValue field

Tags: c#, default-value, custom-properties

I am trying to set a custom C# control property.

Here's my code:

```
/* Cancel's button text */
[Category("ComboTouch"),
Description("Text to display in cancel button"),
DefaultValue("Cancel")]
public String ct_cancelButtonText { get; set; }
```

I can get the property when I use the customized control in other projects (as you can see in the image); but configuration parameter `DefaultValue` seems not to work.

Could anybody help me? Thank you very much.

[image: Custom Control Properties]

**01/10/13** Update. Thank you very much for your answers, you solved my problem.

I would like to share how I finally could set the default value automatically:

```
  private String m_cancelButtonText="Cancel";

    /* Cancel's button text */
    [Category("ComboTouch"),
    Description("Text to display in cancel button"),
    DefaultValue("Cancel")]
    public String ct_cancelButtonText
    {
        get
        {
            return m_cancelButtonText;
        }
        set
        {
            m_cancelButtonText = value;
        }
    }
```

One curiosity: please check the format of 'Cancel' text. If I set DefaultValue type; it looks like normal text. But if I don't, it looks like **bold text**. I know it's silly; but I would like to know why it is that way. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Default values in the properties tab in visual studio show as normal text and changed properties show as Bold. Somehow VS is identifying that it wasnt set by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx):

> A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

Comment: And when you do so, ensure that you use a single (private) constant for both the DefaultValue() and the field initialization. Don't type the same thing in twice. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem. I edited the question with sample code and one more question.